# Apply function not working in R

Tags: r, apply

I created a data frame :

```
fy <- c(2010,2011,2012,2010,2011,2012,2010,2011,2012)
company <-c("Apple","Apple","Apple","Google","Google","Google","Microsoft","Microsoft","Microsoft")
revenue <- c(65225,108249,156508,29321,37905,50175,62484,69943,73723) 
profit <- c(14013,25922,41733,8505,9737,10737,18760,23150,16978)
companiesData <- data.frame(fy, company, revenue, profit)
```

I am trying to create new column using apply command but it is given error:

```
companiesData$Margin<-apply(companiesData,1,function(x){(x[4]/x[3])*100})
```

> Error in x[4]/x[3] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Can someone please tell me what is the mistake here?

Comment: why are you looping? Isn't this what you need? `100*(companiesData$profit/companiesData$revenue)`

Answer (score 4):

The mistake is that `apply` coerces its first argument to a matrix and since `companiesData` has numeric and non-numeric variables, all variables are converted to non-numeric resulting in the operation `x/y` being invalid, because division is not defined for non-numeric data.

Solution: you don't need `apply` in this case.

```
companiesData$Margin <- 100 * companiesData$profit / companiesData$revenue
```

or equivalently

```
companiesData <- within(companiesData, Margin <- 100 * profit / revenue)
```

do what you want.

Comment: why would your second option be better than the first? Is there a performance difference or any other advantage? As far as I can tell readability is about the same between the two - Good explanation on the `apply` though

Comment: @Sotos There is no difference in performance. It's a matter of style and readability.